# I wanted to know if calculating body temperature using KINECT's IR camera

Tags: video-camera

So i am doing a project where i want to fetch the body temperature using kinect. I know that it has an IR sensor built into it, but am not sure if it is capable of measuring the body temperature. Please guide.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think it's possible to do any accurate thermal reading with the Kinect.

Using [Kinect SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44561) you can customize and extend the functionality of the Kinect, but the sensor just isn't build for doing accurate temperatur readings.

The infrared emitter output on the Kinect is too diffuse and its field of view is too wide. The Kinect also doesn't cover the entire infrared wave length (.9 - 14μm) necessary to do any accurate thermal imaging.